# WP Query вывод paginate_links

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```
<?php
  global $post;
  $current_page = !empty( $_GET['blog'] ) ? $_GET['blog'] : 1;

  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'paged'          => $current_page,
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
      ?>
      вывод html работает отлично
      <?php
    }

    echo paginate_links( array(
      'base' => site_url() . '%_%',
      'format' => '/blog/%#%',
      'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
      'current' => $current_page,
    ) );

    wp_reset_postdata();
  } 
?>
```

Пагинация выводится правильно. Но ссылки не работают. То есть страницы 1-2-3 имеют ссылки "blog/2/3", при нажатии на них происходит редирект на blog. То есть страницы "/blog/2" нет. Не понимаю причину.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `'format'`, а в base прописать следующее `'base' => user_trailingslashit( wp_normalize_path( get_permalink() .'/%#%/' ) ),`

Comment: @Simon Перебрасывает на самый последний пост в данной странице, то есть 12й, при клике на любую страницу пагинации. Выглядит так: url/post-name/2( или 3)

Comment: Вам нужно написать `wp_reset_postdata();` ДО `paginate_links();`, так же я бы заменил ваш `$current_page = !empty( $_GET['blog'] ) ? $_GET['blog'] : 1;` на `get_query_var( 'page' );` и `'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оформлю в ответ, в комментах не очень удобно, каша получается. Протестил локально, так должно работать:

```
  $args = [
    'posts_per_page'=> 12,
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'paged'         => get_query_var( 'page' ),
  ];

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      вывод html работает отлично
      <?php
    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo paginate_links( [
      'base'    => user_trailingslashit( wp_normalize_path( get_permalink() .'/%#%/' ) ),
      'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
      'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) )
    ] );

  endif;
```

Comment: Аналогично получается. url/post-name/2( или 3)

Comment: У меня сначала был шаблон страницы. Я подумал, что не верно это и сделал шаблон данной категории. Но всё равно ничего не помогло. Было page-news, стало category-news

Comment: Так а зачем вам тогда в шаблоне категории WP_Query? Чем стандартный цикл не подходит?

Comment: Тем, что шаблон вывода карточек не подходит мне. Я, видимо, где-то что-то напутал. Сам цикл подходит

Comment: Ну так шаблон вывода карточек можете заменить на другой, вам же в принципе никто не мешает) Просто ипользуйте другой template part в цикле и все)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Проблему решил. Надо было внимательнее учиться) Вот скриншот всего решения. http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2020/11/10/0014/0699/975547/47/108c4763f4.jpg

Comment: Отлично! Но на всякий случай) Если у вас стандартный цикл, его не нужно сбрасывать, потому можете убрать `wp_reset_postdata();`, к тому же `wp_reset_postdata();` работает только с `WP_Query`

Comment: Благодарю)  На всякий случай, может кому-то понадобится. Можно не увеличивать посты в цикле через functions, а просто прописать их в админке . http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2020/11/10/0014/0699/975547/47/40a4edbb81.jpg