# WP Вывод пагинации для произвольного типа записи

Tags: php, wordpress, пагинация

Имеется произвольный тип записи `news` задается в `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', function () {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'News',
        'singular_name' => 'News',
        'add_new' => 'Add News',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add News',
        'edit_item' => 'Corrected news',
        'new_item' => 'New news',
        'all_items' => 'All news',
        'search_items' => 'Search news',
        'not_found' => 'News in these types were not found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No such news were found in the basket',
        'menu_name' => 'News'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt2',
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,

    );

    register_post_type('news', $args);
});
```

В нем задано 15 данных записей. Задача на странице `page-news.php` вывести записи с пагинацией по 5 страниц.
Вот код подключения.

```
<div id="response" class="block_list">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',

    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title();
            echo '<div class="block_item">
                    <a class="block_item__link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $title . '</a>
              </div>';
        endwhile; ?>

        <div class="category_pagination">
        <?php
        $current_page = !empty( $_GET['news'] ) ? $_GET['news'] : 1;
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => 'page/%#%/',
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $current_page,
            'show_all' => false,
            'end_size' => 1,
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_next' => true,
            'prev_text' => __('Previous', 'proyob'),
            'next_text' => __('Next', 'proyob'),
            'class' => '',
        ) );
        ?>
        </div>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?><p><?php esc_html_e('Missing posts with defined criteria', 'test'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Пагинация, отображает [paginate_links()](https://misha.agency/wordpress/paginate_links.html), но при нажатие на ссылку отображает не контент новой страницы, а `index.php`.

Comment: А зачем вообще делать отдельный квери для пагинации? Ну и по классике [https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/). `get_the_posts_pagination()` не сработает, так как если посмотрите в код функции, то она работает с глобальным `$wp_query` + под капотом она все равно использует [paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/).

Comment: Как-то понятнее не стало. Но, соглашусь стандартную пагинацию оно тоже не отображает. Можно подробнее, что необходимо поменять, что б оно начало отображать пагинацию ?

Comment: Есть такая глобальная переменная в WordPress как `$wp_query`, можете сделать `var_dump()` и посмотреть что там будет (это глобальный инстанс WP_Query). Так как Вы выводите Ваши произвольные записи в шаблоне страницы, то и глобальный `WP_Query` будет в себе содержать `query` и `query_vars` для страницы news, где `$wp_query->max_num_pages` будет равен 0. Если посмотреть в код функции, то там будет проверка в которой говорится, что если основной запрос ($wp_query) содержит менее 1 страницы, то пагинация не выводится.

Comment: Чтобы отображало пагинацию, используйте  `paginate_links()`

Comment: Ну либо можно переопределить глобальную переменную `$wp_query` с Вашим `$pagination_query`, а потом обратно, но это плохая практика.

Comment: Ok, Если вызов функции `echo paginate_links()` в теле цикла, тоже ничего не возвращает . Что делать ?

Comment: Приложите код, но обычно эта функция используется вне цикла.

Comment: Код вопроса заменил. Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: У тебя много ненужного в коде.  Поудаляй для начала дефолтные/ненужные значения. (я про `$args`)

Comment: Переписал. Нашел, ещё вот такая же проблема была https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202588/wp-query-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-paginate-links , но что-то для моего запроса это не помогло. Я так понимаю что у меня не верное задается значение `'paged'` или `'current'` но как это для кастомного типа записи, не понимаю.

Comment: убери вообще `paged`. и 'query_var' тебе не нужно. Читай документацию по функциям.

Comment: Убрал, но оно ни как не влияет на отображения контента при переходе по ссылкам.

Comment: А так? `echo paginate_links(['base' => user_trailingslashit(wp_normalize_path(get_permalink() .'/%#%/')), 'current' => max(1, get_query_var('page')), 'total' => $query->max_num_pages]);`

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Результат тот же. При нажатии на ссылку не отображает контент который должен иметь отношение к текущим постам при пагинации.

Comment: Я не вижу всего твоего кода, да и не надо.. Ты в очередной раз находишь приключения на ровном месте. Если всё сделать по манам то всё работает. В общем выкинь это всё, возьми [вот тут](https://generatewp.com/) заново сгенери  тип поста и таксономии, возьми нормальную тему (удали свой шаблон) и увидишь что всё работает без танцев. (мне на это понадобилось буквально 10 минут с генерацией контента. См [в песочнице](https://toon-power-dapu.instawp.xyz/arttaxs/quos-maxime/))

Comment: @BlackStar1991 не совсем понял какой результат и что не так отображается, но в аргументы `$query` нужно передавать номер текущей страницы.

Comment: Проблема в том, что Пагинация для обычных страниц/постов, это одно. Пагинация для Архивных страниц/категорий/тегов это другое. А вот с произвольными типами записи, тут начинаются 3-и танцы с бубном. Вот какой-то толковый совет нашел... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176723/creating-a-simple-pagination-for-custom-post-type-templates  Но пока не получилось нормально подключить.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы в пагианции для предустановленных и кастомных сущностей.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-то пригодиться ответ.
При объявлении кастомного типа записи, его `slug` не должен совпадать со слагом страниц/постов/категорий и тд.

При правке кастомного типа записи необходимо пересохнанять `Settings/Permalink Settings`
Вид произвольной типа записи в `functions.php` .

```
add_action('init', function () {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'News',
        'singular_name' => 'News',
        'add_new' => 'Add News',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add News',
        'edit_item' => 'Corrected news',
        'new_item' => 'New news',
        'all_items' => 'All news',
        'search_items' => 'Search news',
        'not_found' => 'News in these types were not found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No such news were found in the basket',
        'menu_name' => 'News'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt2',
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),

        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'query_var' => 'new',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'new',
        ),

    );

    register_post_type('news', $args);
});
```

Особое внимание к параметрам `'hierarchical' => true, 'has_archive'   => true,` Что б выводило пагинацию этих кастомных постов с пагинацией.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <div id="response" class="block_list">
                <?php
                $current = absint(
                    max(
                        1,
                        get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'news' )
                    )
                );
                $query = new WP_Query(
                    [
                        'post_type' => 'news',
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'paged' => $current,
                    ]
                );

                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                        $title = get_the_title();
                        echo '<div class="block_item">
                                <a class="block_item__link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $title . '</a>
                             </div>';
                    endwhile; ?>

                    <div class="category_pagination">
                        <?php
                        echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                            'format' => 'page/%#%/',
                            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                            'show_all' => false,
                            'end_size' => 1,
                            'mid_size' => 2,
                            'prev_next' => true,
                            'prev_text' => __('Previous', 'test'),
                            'next_text' => __('Next', 'test'),
                            'class' => '',
                        ) );
                        ?>
                    </div>

                <?php }
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php else : ?><p><?php esc_html_e('Missing posts with defined criteria', 'test'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```